# Mocking HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0

I have a controller Action as:

```
[HttpPost]
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("PostData")]
public async Task<string> PostData(HttpRequestMessage message)
{

//Do operations
}
```

I need to create a mock for this method ,but I am not getting how to pass the parameter "HttpRequestMessage",

because if there was any variable to be passed , then its just initializing with the type like string or int.

How to handle this condition in mock?

Comment: Create an instance of the request, populate it with what's relevant for the test and pass that to the method under test.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpRequestMessage` is very mutable:

```
public class HttpRequestMessage : IDisposable
{
    [... ctors]

    public Version Version { get; set; }
    public HttpContent Content { get; set; }
    public HttpMethod Method { get; set; }
    public Uri RequestUri { get; set; }
    public HttpRequestHeaders Headers { get; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; }

    [... Dispose, ToString]
}
```

So if you just need to set `RequestUri` for example, you can:

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage() { RequestUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com") };
yourClassInstance.PostData(requestMessage);
```

Even if you need to add some headers or [properties `GetRequestContext` can create `HttpRequestContext` from](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/asp-net-web-api-2-and-httprequestcontext/), you can do

```
requestMessage.Headers.Add("h", "v");
requestMessage.Properties.Add("p", "v");
```

This design (of `HttpRequestMessage`) does not adhere to functional programming principles at all, but at least you can test it easily.

Comment: I originally looked at the `HttpRequestMessage` definition and thought `Headers` wouldn't be mockable because of it being a read-only property, but not realizing that you can `Add()` the headers like that. Glad I found this. 